# Deploying PHP Laravel 4.2 to Heroku fails

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-4

I've got a simple Laravel 4.2 app that works on my local Homestead machine.     I'm running OSX Yosemite, with VirtualBox.

I can't however deploy it to Heroku.  I've got a basic Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

I've also set my build pack using

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php
```

This is the output I get when I run the following command from my mac terminal:

```
git push heroku master
```

OUTPUT:

```
Counting objects: 4305, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4100/4100), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4305/4305), 4.18 MiB | 93.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4305 (delta 1298), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/php
remote: -----> PHP app detected
remote: -----> Bootstrapping...
remote: -----> Installing system packages...
remote:        NOTICE: No runtime required in composer.json; requirements
remote:        from dependencies in composer.lock will be used for selection
remote:        - php (7.0.3)
remote:        - Apache (2.4.16)
remote:        - Nginx (1.8.0)
remote: -----> Enabling PHP extensions...
remote:        - ext-zend-opcache (automatic)
remote: -----> Installing dependencies...
remote:        Composer version 1.0.0-alpha11 2015-11-14 16:21:07
remote:        Loading composer repositories with package information
remote:        Installing dependencies from lock file
remote:          - Installing guzzlehttp/streams (2.1.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (4.2.3)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/translation (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/security-core (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/routing (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/process (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.8.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/debug (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/finder (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/css-selector (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/console (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/browser-kit (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing stack/builder (v1.0.3)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing predis/predis (v0.8.7)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing phpseclib/phpseclib (0.3.10)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing patchwork/utf8 (v1.3.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.17.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing monolog/monolog (1.17.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing nikic/php-parser (v0.9.5)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing jeremeamia/superclosure (1.0.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing ircmaxell/password-compat (v1.0.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing filp/whoops (1.1.10)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing d11wtq/boris (v1.0.8)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/filesystem (v2.8.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing classpreloader/classpreloader (1.0.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing laravel/framework (v4.2.19)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:        Generating optimized autoload files
remote:        > php artisan clear-compiled
remote:        Mcrypt PHP extension required.
remote:        Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
remote:        
remote:        
remote:                              
remote:          [RuntimeException]  
remote:          Error Output:       
remote:                              
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
remote:        
remote:        
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to agile-wildwood-99938.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/agile-wildwood-99938.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/agile-wildwood-     99938.git'
```

Its worth noting on my local machine, when I run (from my laravel project root folder)

```
php artisan
```

I get a message similar to the output from the Heroku deploy, namely

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
```

I don't know if this is relevant?  Could absence of Mcrypt on my local machine effect the Heroku deploy, or is the Heroku output referring entirely to the Heroku server?

I'm struggling a bit here. Would appreciate some help.

Thanks kindly
Charlie

Comment: mcrypt is essential for Laravel and I don't think it will work without it, you have to install it on the Heroku "box" or whatever that is called.

Comment: Wanna accept the answer, Charlie?

Answer (score 2):

If your application requires the MCrypt extension then you need to enable it by adding `exr-mcrypt` as a requirement to your `composer.json`. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions

Comment: Follow the instructions in the documentation. You need to `composer update` and commit the changes lock file as well.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I was missing composer update.